# How to replace node tabs with jQuery ones

Tags: 6, javascript, routes

I use Drupal 6 and the content profile module in order to create user profiles for my site users. Also i use panels 3 module in order to make a blog page with path /user/%user/blog for every user attached as a menu tab in each one profile page. Now i want to ask if there is a way to replace node tabs as "Home" "Edit" and "Blog" with jQuery ones. Thanks in advance.